# How to subscribe the sensor values into ros nodes and to publish results to controll servo motors?

Tags: ros, 3d-object-recognition

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use the sensor values inside the ros node to do some operation and than after doing some operation by using them i want to send the result values to the actuaters of the robot with BBB, how can i do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234630/how-to-subscribe-the-sensor-values-into-ros-nodes-and-to-publish-results-to-controll-servo-motors-?/) by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 932 on 2016-05-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need a package to subscribe to a topic published by the sensor's package then publish it as another topic containing the values you need. After that you can subscribe again to do your traitement..

To do that you need:

Writing a Simple Publisher and Subscriber (C++):
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29

Or more advance tutorial where you can create your own message type:
http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/DefiningCustomMessages

---

Originally posted by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) with karma: 751 on 2016-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinesh](https://answers.ros.org/users/26847/dinesh/) on 2016-05-19**:
Thank u very much for your precious feedback.